# 16.04 Unable to fetch some archives

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates, update-manager

I've tried everything to fix the error `E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`.

I've tried cleaning the apt-get system, using `install -f`, obviously using `fix-missing` and `update` or `upgrade`.

The output of my `sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev`:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-   opensource-src/libqt5xml5_5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 50.7.82.37 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/qtbase5-dev-tools_5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 50.7.82.37 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/qtbase5-dev_5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 50.7.82.37 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5opengl5-dev_5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 50.7.82.37 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qtbase-opensource-src/libqt5sql5-sqlite_5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 50.7.82.37 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The output of `update`:

```
Fetched 109 kB in 3s (34,9 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' as repository 'http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'arm64'
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 50.7.82.35 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 50.7.82.35 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 50.7.82.35 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried everything I've seen on other questions and other forums but I really don't know how to solve it.

Do you have any idea?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

Added some terminal outputs

```
~: dpkg --print-architecture
amd64
```

And

```
~: dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386
arm64
```

Comment: can you show `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg   --print-foreign-architectures`. Please edit you question for that.

Comment: @user966203 added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo dpkg  --remove-architecture arm64
```

If you have crosscompile tools on your System you will get an error similiar like

```
Architektur »arm64«, is in use, can not be removed
```

an overview gives

```
dpkg -l | awk '/:arm64/{ print $2 }'
```

If so you can remove them with `sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/:arm64/{ print $2 }')` and remove the architecture `sudo dpkg  --remove-architecture arm64`

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you explain why this architecture cause this error?

Comment: No I'm sorry. I never use it.  No multiarch on my System.